# Shiny app not deploying when publishing to shinyapps.io but works fine locally

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploy an app to shinyapps.io but keep getting "application failed to start" the error logs are:

```
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292437+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: R version: 3.2.2
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292513+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: shiny version: 0.12.2
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292515+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: rmarkdown version: NA
2016-01-20T22:44:49.540081+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292516+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: knitr version: NA
2016-01-20T22:44:49.540083+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Starting R with process         ID: '11'
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292517+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: jsonlite version: 0.9.17
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292529+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2016-01-20T22:44:49.292531+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2016-01-20T22:44:49.536599+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Using jsonlite for JSON   processing
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833246+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.835703+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833250+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2016-01-20T22:44:49.841626+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: The following objects are     masked from ‘package:base’:
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833251+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.841628+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833953+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833959+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.841631+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833955+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:49.841629+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833957+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:     arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
2016-01-20T22:44:49.833958+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:     summarize
2016-01-20T22:44:49.835701+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2016-01-20T22:44:49.835704+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:     filter, lag
2016-01-20T22:44:49.835705+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:51.532816+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Note: the specification for S3 class “family” in package ‘MatrixModels’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘lme4’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
2016-01-20T22:44:52.010843+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Loading required package: gridExtra
2016-01-20T22:44:52.368688+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Loading required package: xlsxjars
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280159+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280162+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Attaching package: ‘zoo’
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280163+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280487+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280489+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280490+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
2016-01-20T22:44:53.280491+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462711+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462715+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: Attaching package: ‘lubridate’
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462967+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: The following object is masked from ‘package:plyr’:
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462968+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462969+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:     here
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462971+00:00 shinyapps[70724]: 
2016-01-20T22:44:53.462716+00:00 shinyapps[70724]:
```

I'm loading the packages as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(car)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotflow)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)
library(RJSONIO)
source("http://peterhaschke.com/Code/multiplot.R")
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
library(fmsb)
library(markdown)
```

::Update::

I've commented out the `library(zoo)` and `library(lubridate)` and get the following:

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
    summarize

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Note: the specification for S3 class “family” in package ‘MatrixModels’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘lme4’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
Loading required package: gridExtra
Loading required package: xlsxjars
```

I have no issues running this locally.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Is that the complete error log? Does it just not load `library(fmsb)`? (That's where it seemed to stop.) If you move that higher up the list, does it quit sooner? It would help to see more of the code you run since that's where the error seems more likely to be.

Comment: I've moved the `library(fmsb)` to the top and it makes no difference I get the same error log.  That is also the entire error log I get. If i remove the the lubridate and zoo packages the error log stops after loading xlsjars (see updated original post)

Comment: Then it seems like it's loading the libraries fine. The problem must be in the code that comes after that but you haven't shared any of that.

Comment: I've updated with the rest of that file(reading csv's and xls)  thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MrFlick I was able to figure it out. It was due to reading a large csv file.  Thanks for helping me get pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to narrow it down to a large .csv file that I was reading.  I think it was taking too long to process. Once I trimmed all the "blank spaces" I was good. Thanks for your help.